# Open link based on combination of selected option and button clicked (html, javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I am posting this question because there are Q&A s with the first part of my question (dropdown options), but I am not sure how to incorporate the 2nd part (buttons).  The scenario is this:

My page has an html dropdown with options: 
Option1 Option2 Option3 Option4 Option5

There are also various buttons:
ButtonA ButtonB ButtonC ButtonD ButtonE

I'd like to send the user to the corresponding page for the Button/Option.

So for example, if the user picks Option 2 and then clicks Button D, I'd like for Button D to open up the ButtonD-Option2 page.
The user could also then click ButtonB, in which case, if the Option has not been changed, I would open the ButtonB-Option2 page.
Or the user could change to Option 3 and click Button D again, and it would open the ButtonD-Option3 page.

So I am back to this, I've tried various things and here is what I have so far:

```
<select id="LineDropdown" onchange="ChangeLineFunc()">
    <option selected value = "000"> Select ... </option>
    <option value = "002">002</option>
    <option value = "003">003</option>
    <option value = "004">004</option>
```

etc ...

The buttons are just a list:

```
<ul>
<li> <input type=button class="button" value = "Button1" onclick="OpenButton1()"/></li>
<li> <input type=button class="button" value = "Button2" onclick="OpenButton2()"/> </li>
```

... etc

I can see what they select:
function ChangeLineFunc(){

```
var LineSelected = document.getElementById( "LineDropdown" );
var LineSelectedValue = LineSelected.options[LineDropdown.selectedIndex].value
// alert( LineSelected.options[LineDropdown.selectedIndex ].value )
alert (LineSelectedValue)
```

}

and I can open a hardcoded page:

```
function OpenButton1() {
location.href("https...Button1/Option2.pdf")
```

}

What I would really like to do is open |

```
location.href("https ... Button1/*selectedoption*.pdf
```

I'd like to stick with the function per Button for now as it is (for me) easier to understand.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code

Comment: Share your HTML

Comment: Yes please post your code as you noted. Welcome to StackOverflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Please share your code too, when you post a question next time. Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kunalarora/xpvt214o/242009/) fiddle, it might do it for you. Here's the js part of it.

```
var combinations = [
  {option:1, button:'a', link:'www.google.com'},
  {option:1, button:'b', link:'www.ustraa.com'},
  {option:2, button:'a', link:'www.ustraa.com'},  
  {option:2, button:'b', link:'www.google.com'},
];
window.handleClick = function(button) {
  var option = $('#select-box').val();
  combinations.forEach(function(c) {
    if (c.option == option && c.button == button) {
      console.log(c.link);
      //window.location = c.link;
    }
  });
}
```